Can I use the partition writable in an Xubuntu 24.4 installation stick for additional purposes?
I made an USB stick (/dev/sdb) with an iso image of Xubuntu 24.04 on it. Looking at its content with lsblk, I saw that there is the fourth partition named writable on it which covers all remaining space on the USB stick:
NAME     SIZE PTTYPE PHY-SEC LOG-SEC PARTFLAGS              VENDOR   MODEL
sdb     58,6G gpt        512     512                        Intenso  Ultra Line
├─sdb1   3,8G gpt        512     512 0x1000000000000001
├─sdb2     5M gpt        512     512
├─sdb3   300K gpt        512     512 0x1000000000000001
└─sdb4  54,8G gpt        512     512

NAME     SIZE FSUSE% FSTYPE   LABEL                   UUID
sdb     58,6G        iso9660  Xubuntu 24.04 LTS amd64 2024-07-07-02-24-32-00
├─sdb1   3,8G   100% iso9660  Xubuntu 24.04 LTS amd64 2024-07-07-02-24-32-00
├─sdb2     5M        vfat     ESP                     37B6-BC6E
├─sdb3   300K
└─sdb4  54,8G        ext4     writable                14e3f2a2-8c6a-421f-9ab7-17256f1653f0

The USB stick is partitioned with the gpt scheme and it has an ESP partition.
Apparently on every boot from the USB stick, a log directory is created in the partition writable.

May I use the partition writable to store files in it which I might use during the installation e.g. scripts or configuration files?

Where is the documentation how to use the accumulating
content in this partition?

May I delete no longer used logs from it?

Does this partition cause the almost endless shutdown time after booting from the USB Disk? In some experiments some years ago with older versions of Ubuntu, persistent partitions caused very long shutdown times and if one unplugged the stick too early, it was gone! Hopefully this has become more stable now!


I have taken a closer look at this partition using the option print of fdisk:
v@w:~$ sudo parted /dev/sdb
GNU Parted 3.4
/dev/sdb wird verwendet
Willkommen zu GNU Parted! Rufen Sie »help« auf, um eine Liste der verfügbaren Befehle zu erhalten.
(parted) print
Modell: Intenso Ultra Line (scsi)
Festplatte  /dev/sdb:  62,9GB
Sektorgröße (logisch/physisch): 512B/512B
Partitionstabelle: gpt
Disk-Flags:
Nummer  Anfang  Ende    Größe   Dateisystem  Name       Flags
 1      32,8kB  4106MB  4106MB               ISO9660    versteckt, msftdata
 2      4106MB  4111MB  5192kB               Appended2  boot, esp
 3      4111MB  4111MB  307kB                Gap1       versteckt, msftdata
 4      4113MB  62,9GB  58,8GB  ext4
(parted) quit
v@w:~$ 


Why does the partitioning look different from what lsblk tells?

If I look at the stick with GPartEd, it only show me one big partition!
